# Prefetch_Related Models Reverse Lookup

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models; 'Post', 'Images'. Where 'Post' is a ForeignKey in 'Images' Model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=120)
    body= models.TextField()

class Images(models.Model):
    post= models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, related_name='images')
    image= models.ImageField(upload_to='company', verbose_name= 'Image')
```

I want to filter all 'image' that belongs to a particular 'post_id'.

I ran the below query with prefetch_related(), but I only got the data related to Post and no image.

```
mop= Post.objects.filter(id=9).prefect_related('images')
print mop
```

End Result

```
[<Post: man, I'm Back, We are moving to London for summer>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the images for a single post, but do not need the post, then you should fetch the images directly.

```
images = Images.objects.filter(post=9)
```

If you want the post as well, then you can do:

```
post = Post.objects.filter(id=9)  # this query isn't needed if you only need the images
images = post.images.all()
```

This causes two queries, one to fetch the post and another to fetch the images.

You can use `prefetch_related` if you want

```
post = Post.objects.filter(id=9).prefetch_related().get()
images = post.images.all()
```

However this still takes two queries, so isn't any more efficient that the code without `prefetch_related`.

The advantage of `prefetch_related` is when you want to fetch the images for all of the posts in a queryset. For example:

```
posts = Post.objects.prefetch_related('images')
for post in posts:
    # this won't cause any additional queries, 
    # because you have already prefetched them
    images = post.images.all()
```

If, for example, the `posts` queryset contains 10 items, then `prefetch_related` will reduce the number of queries from 11 (one for the post and 10 to fetch the images for each post individually) to two (one for the post and one to fetch all the images at once).

Comment: Thaks for the reply. I understand your first query.. Would have done that but I don't want to hit the DB twice, since prefetch_related hit it once. Why I said twice is, mop= Post.objects.filter(id=9), myphoto= Images.objects.filter(image=mop), for my in myphoto: return my. and this will hit twice..Hope you get my point?

Comment: You still have two database queries if you use `prefetch_related` - one to fetch the posts, and one to fetch the related images. The advantage of `prefetch_related` is if you have (say) 10 posts, then you still have two queries. Without `prefetch_related` you would have one query to fetch the posts and 10 queries to fetch the images.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
images_related_to_mop = mop.images.all()
```

which will get the related images already *pre-fetched* by the query.